# Does the BIOS run on the CPU?

Tags: computer-architecture

I was just thinking about this: Does the BIOS execute on the CPU? If so, how does it handle multiple CPU architectures/instruction sets? If not, what does it execute on?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is a very basic one. Since you [did not include much of an attempt to solve it on your own](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594), we have little to work with. Start with a simple search, find [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS#Operation), try to solve your by yourself before asking here. If you still have questions, then edit your post to reflect your work and we can give you a clear answer.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't think that this is a computer *science* question. The BIOS is an implementation detail, not a concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the processor itself runs the BIOS boot program. Each motherboard has to be equipped with appropriate BIOS that a processor of compatible chip set can use.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The bios is just software stored on a chip. It has a special memory address, and the CPU is hardwired to execute the program in that address when it turns on.